# Django-CMS: list all placeholder from page

Tags: django, django-cms

When creating a placeholder on template (using template `{% placeholder "example" %}`), it doesn't show on `page.placeholders.all()`, only on "content" placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

## Solved

calling rescan_placeholders() on page instance.